# Place caret in the end of text in contenteditable while navigating with up/down arrow keys

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to place caret at the end of text while navigating with arrow keys up/down. If I change `contenteditable` to input, it works, because I just add `event.preventDefault()`. But I can't use input, only `contenteditable`.

However, with `contenteditable` the caret jumps to the beginning of the line once I use up/down arrow keys. Here is a snippet:

```js
    var li = $('li.test');
      var liSelected;
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 40) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (liSelected) {
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.next();
            if (next.length > 0) {
              liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
              liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
            }
          } else {
            liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
          }
        } else if (e.which === 38) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (liSelected) {
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.prev();
            if (next.length > 0) {
              liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
              // liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
            }
          } else {
            // liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
          }
        }
        $('li.selected .single-line').focus();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = 'main'>
<ul>
   <li class="test"><div id = 'n1' contenteditable=true class="single-line"> Content one</div></li>
   <li class="test"> <div id = 'n2' contenteditable=true class="single-line">Test</div></li>
   <li class="test"> <div id = 'n3' contenteditable=true class="single-line"> Content 3</div></li>
   <li class="test"> <div id = 'n4' contenteditable=true class="single-line"> Content 4</div></li>
</ul>
    
   

   
</div>
```

Comment: When place it in the end?..

Comment: At the end of text, you can see that by default, contenteditable place caret at start of text, I want caret at the end of text

Comment: I don't see that. The caret appears in the place I clicked, not in the beginning of the text.

Comment: But, I mean while navigation with arrow keys, you can see that caret is always at start. Do I make myself clear?

Comment: [No, you don't.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BAezv.gif) The navigation works properly.

Comment: Click on one list, and press down arrow key, you can see that cursor goes through list, but in the start of text

Comment: Ah, now that's clear.